# ReactJS high order components not forwarding property in a render loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for a little guidance.  I have followed the [React Drag-n-Drop chess tutorial](http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/examples-chessboard-tutorial-app.html) applying the same principles to my project. But I got stuck when a Child Class needs to recursively repeat.  When Child is rendered from the Parent everything works.  But when I recursively render a Child from a Child render function I get errors about missing default props that should have been forwarded by DragSource( ) according to how high order components work.  I will give the console output of the props below the code.

In the code below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

**Constants.js**

```
export const ItemTypes = {
  CHILD: 'child'
}
```

**Parent.jsx**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd'
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd/modules/backends/HTML5'

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Child />
    ) 
  }
}

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Parent)
```

**Child.jsx**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { ItemTypes } from './Constants'
import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd'

const taskSource = {
  beginDrag (props) {
    return {
      index: props.index
    }
  }
}

function collect (connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  static get propTypes () {
    return {
      index: PropTypes.number,
      connectDragSource: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      isDragging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    console.log(props)

    this.state = {
      children: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
  }

  render () {
      const { connectDragSource, isDragging } = this.props

      return connectDragSource(
          <ul className='children'>
            { this.state.children.map((child, i) =>
              <li key={child}>
                <Child index={i} ref={'child/' + i} />
              </li>
            ) }
          </ul>
      )
  }
}

export default DragSource(ItemTypes.CHILD, taskSource, collect)(Child)
```

**Console.log output of Child Component props when called from the Parent Component render function**

```
{
  _id: "123"",
  connectDragSource: fn(),
  isDragging: false
}
```

**Console.log output of Child Component props when called recursively from the Child Component render function**

```
{
  _id: "1234"
  index: 0
}

ERROR: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: connectDragSource is not a function
```

So basically what I think is happening is the high order components are not forwarding the default props to the Child Component rendered from the Child Component loop.

I would love any advice anyone may have as I have been digging into this for a few hours now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

So it is actually a really simple answer I have learned.  The imported child in Parent.jsx is not the same child as in Child.jsx.  The Child class in parent has the behavior of the high order component while the child reference to itself has yet to have the high order component applied.  To get around this issue I had to do this in Child.jsx:

```
render () {
  const { connectDragSource, isDragging } = this.props

  return connectDragSource(
      <ul className='children'>
        { this.state.children.map((child, i) =>
          <li key={child}>
            <HigherChild index={i} ref={'child/' + i} />
          </li>
        ) }
      </ul>
  )
}

const HigherChild = DragSource(ItemTypes.CHILD, taskSource, collect)(Child)

export default HigherChild
```

Comment: Thanks. What I would love to understand is why doing something like:
`<li key={child}>
     DragSource(ItemTypes.Child, taskSource, collect)(<Child index={i} ref={'child/' + i} />)
</li>`
won't work directly from JSX